# Object of Class A as member in class B. B requires object of A to initialize itself

Tags: c++, design-patterns

RequestStreamer just want to help Request for streaming. Is there a better way to implement it as opposed to what you are seeing below?

What design pattern would this kind of code fit into? Would it be an owner pattern or helper pattern?

This example helps to show the relationship between A and B.

```
class Request {
    RequestStreamer* streamer;
    int contentLen;

public:
    Request()
    {
        contentLen = 0;
        streamer = new RequestStreamer(this);
    }
    ~Request()
    {
        delete streamer;
    }
    int getContentLen()
    {
        return contentLen;
    }
    bool initialize ()
    {
        // Code to update 'contentLen' by reading from source request object.
        // <code>
        if (streamer) streamer->initialize();
    }
    bool sendReq()
    {
        streamer->streamReq();
    }
    int getBytes (int nBytes)
    {
        // some code to read nBytes from the input source of this request object
    }
};

class RequestStreamer {
    Request* req;
    bool bEnabled;
    int chunkSize;

public:
    RequestStreamer(Request* aobj)
    {
        chunkSize = 1024*1024;
        req = aobj;
    }
    ~RequestStreamer()
    {
    }
    bool initialize()
    {
        if (req && req->getContentLen() > chunkSize)
            bEnabled = true;
    }
    bool streamReq()
    {
        if (!req) return false;

        // Assume that there exists socket object implementation already
        if (bEnabled)
        {
            while (req->getBytes(chunkSize) != -1)
                socket->send(req->getBytes(chunkSize));
        }
        else
        {
            socket->send(req->getBytes(req->getContentLen()));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: *I don't have proper example to represent the relationship between A and B.* Makes picking a structure appropriate to their relationship kind of impossible then.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you are leaking memory.

Comment: If `A` and `B` were real world objects what would they representing ? Is `A` something like a car and `B` the engine ? Its really hard to draw a picture and ideally structure it when the object names are so vague like `A` and `B`

Comment: @PrimRock, Updated code. Hope this example helps in understanding the relation

Comment: @Rakete1111, Thanks for pointing out. Updated code with destructor.

Comment: code won't compile you made destructor and constructor private thus you cannot instantiate class Request.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code: A also requires object of B to initialize itself.
Which means there is an association 1 <-> 1 between the 2 classes.
Both of the classes need an pointer to each other(and this is not "B helping A", because there is a strong correlation between the classes).
But to make sure RequestStreamer can be only made from Request, turn out its constructor to private and make Request a friend class.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of patterns in here - but they're not clear, and the classes seem to be confused about their roles.

I'd split the classes up a bit and use a dose of the strategy pattern - and pass the strategy / data in as the Request constructor arguments. All this would give something a bit more like this. (There's still a lot of potential clean up here .. but I think the intent and separation of concerns is clearer)

```
// What I'm sending
class IRequestContent {
   virtual int getContentLen() = 0;
   int getBytes (int nBytes) = 0;
};

// How I'm sending it
class IRequestStreamerStrategy {
   virtual bool initialize(IRequestContent * content, IRequest * req) = 0;
   virtual bool streamReq(IRequestContent * content) = 0;
};

// The combination of what I'm sending and how I'm sending it
class Request : public IRequest {
    shared_ptr<IRequestStreamerStrategy> streamer;
    shared_ptr<IRequestContent> content;

public:
    Request(
        shared_ptr<IRequestStreamerStrategy> streamer,
        shared_ptr<IRequestContent> content
    ) : streamer(streamer), content(content)
    {}

    bool initialize () {
        streamer->initialize(content, this);
    }

    bool sendReq() {
        return streamer->streamReq(content);
    }
};

class RequestStreamer : public IRequestStreamerStrategy {

    bool bEnabled;
    int chunkSize;

public:
    RequestStreamer() { chunkSize = 1024*1024; }

    bool initialize(IRequestContent * content) {
        if ( content->getContentLen() > chunkSize )
            bEnabled = true;
    }

    bool streamReq(IRequestContent * content) {
        if (!req) return false;

        // Assume that there exists socket object implementation already
        if (bEnabled) {
            while (content->getBytes(chunkSize) != -1)
                socket->send(content->getBytes(chunkSize));
        } else {
            socket->send(content->getBytes(content->getContentLen()));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring constructor and destructor private in class Request thus you cannot instantiate your class (accessing private member data).

- also you make class Request contains a pointer to class RequestStreamer so you must `forward declare` class RequestStreamer.
- you make class RequestStreamer `contains` a pointer to class Request so each of the tow classes has a pointer to each other and thus `each class must be implemented before the other` because you cannot use incomplete objects. as result you cannot solve it in that way.
- to solve it consider using templates:
  here is an example of templates:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  template <class T> class A;
  template <class T> class B;

  template <class T>
  class A
  {
      public:
          A();
          ~A();
      private:
          B<T>* ptrB;
  };

  template <class T>
  class B
  {
      public:
          B();
          ~B();
      private:
          A<T>* ptrA;
  };

  template <class T>
  B<T>::B() : ptrA(new A<T>)
  {}

  template <class T>
  B<T>::~B()
  {
      delete ptrA;
  }

  template <class T>
  A<T>::A() : ptrB(new B<T>){}
  template <class T>
  A<T>::~A() { delete ptrB;}

  int main()
  {
      A<int> a;
      B<char> b;

      return 0;
  }
  ```